# How to extract value in double quotes from a response header in karate

Tags: karate

I want a specific value from the response header etag.

Response header:

```
etag: W/"118-pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00"
```

Karate Code:

```
    * def etag = responseHeaders['etag'][0]
    * print 'Value of Etag is', etag
    * def etagValue = etag.substring(etag.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)
    * print 'Value of Etag is', etagValue
```

It is giving me the value of complete etag which is expected. Now I want to only get specific values as below.

etag variable has value

```
W/"118-pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00"
```

etagValue variable has value here how to remove double quotes from end

```
pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00"
```

Expected value where - is left boundary and " is right boundary of the value I need.

```
pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` two times. Here you go:

```
* def etag = 'W/"118-pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00"'
* def temp1 = etag.substring(etag.indexOf('-') + 1)
* def temp2 = temp1.substring(0, temp1.indexOf('"'))
* match temp2 == 'pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00'
```

For completeness, there is also a [`karate.extract()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-extract) API that can use regex:

```
* def extracted = karate.extract(etag, '-([^\\"]+)"', 1)
* match extracted == 'pbdwwFo9SKNhD3Lx5iHJyngpq00'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. It was so easy to do. cool

Comment: Thanks. The second way is more effective one so I will use karate.extract().